# Animation over a static jpeg picture

Tags: gimp, animation, background, gif, jpg

I have a (simple) animation gif file (produced using gimp) and a static jpeg picture. I would like to put the animation gif file into the jpeg picture. How can I achieve that without losing the quality of the underlying jpeg picture (converting it to gif does not seem to be an option) ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "put the animation gif file into the jpeg picture"?

Answer (score 1):

Put it where? On an html document? Just float them one above the other.

- Depending on the colors and if you have set a transparency this can work.
- If you need the animation to blend perfectly you need to re-export the animation with the background included, and use other method than gif. CSS sprite animation or a video.
- Or make a png css sprite animation with transparency and put that over the jpg floating it or using double background with css.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to overlay a GIF on a JPEG, you can use SVG with two `<image>` tags. It can then be treated as a single image anywhere SVGs are supported.

Here's an example of an SVG with a JPEG and a GIF in it, although it's probably not much like what you *specifically* want: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgvxgp?editors=100

Comment: And how is that done? Showing only an example is not very helpful ... Please explain with your own words!